# C# Equivalent to StringBuilder's Insert Method for Bytes

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, memorystream

Is there some equivalent to the `StringBuilder.Insert` method for use with byte arrays? I was going to try and use a `MemoryStream` but an error was thrown telling me that the `MemoryStream` object is "not expandable". I need to place bytes within specific spots of another (already existing byte array).

Here is the same idea using StringBuilder.

```
String firstString = "FirstData";
String someString = "string Data";
int Index = 0;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(firstString);

for(int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i++)
{
   sb.Insert(index, someString[i]);
   index += 2;

}
```

Thank you for any help,

Evan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx); which will allow you to insert as needed. If you have an existing array you can call `ToList()`.

```
List<byte> data1 = new List<byte>() {10, 11, 12};
List<byte> data2 = new List<byte>() {13, 14, 15};
int Index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < data1.Count; i++)
{
   data2.Insert(index, data2[i]);
   index += 2;
}
```

Then to go back to an array simply call `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of bytes as opposed to an array of byte and use the insert method there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `List`, it has an `Insert` method

Answer (score 0):

A "Stream" by definition flows only one way. There is no way to change something once it's flowed out the gate. If you want this ability, you'll have to create a regular in-memory collection of some kind to give yourself a buffer you can modify before attempting to push the data out to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a byte array, instead of creating some collection of bytes:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("yourString");
```

or:

```
byte[] utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("yourString");
```

Use ASCII or UTF8 or any other conversation.